# snowflake warehouse: Will it trigger different warehouse instance for each worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am trying to understand how the snowflake warehouses are working

I have opened three worksheets and run the below commands inside each of them

```
use role testrole;
use warehouse testwh;
use database testdb;
use schema testschema;
select * from testtable; <-- has 30k rows
```

Now will it create  three seperate warehouse instances of `testwh` and run inside each of them the above commands.

or will it create only one warehouseinstance of `testwh` and run the above command parallely

Are warehouse instances per worksheet basis or can multiple worksheets share same warehouse instance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will always use `testwh`.
And yes, all worksheets will use same warehouse unless you switch using `use warehosue`  command.

Warehouse instances are independant of worksheet/parallel queries. Some warehouse can run upto 100s of parallel queries. So, if you open 101 sheets in parallel and running SQL same time, 101st query will wait in queue until one is freed. however you can `Auto Scale` using multi cluster warehouse where warehouse will scale up and down as per number of queries etc.

Warehouses can be created either using UI or using `CREATE WAREHOUSE`  statement by admin.

[image: UI Warehouse]

Comment: I am asking about the instances of test_wh

will it create seperate instance or use same instances

Comment: it will use same instance.

Comment: Then what is the use of warehose.

i want a separate instance of the warehouse spineed up, whenever i use `use warehouse test_wh`

Comment: then use `create warehouse` first. Then fire `use warehouse` command to use.